# Disk Space Shortage since cron job setup

Tags: cron, disk-usage, wget, disk-management

I recently setup a cron job on my system which runs the following hourly task:

```
wget -O - http://domain.com/?warm_cache=OUc37lgS2 >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Since setting this up, I've rapidly run out of disk space. So, I'm wondering if there is anything related to the above command that could potentially be responsible.

From my understanding the `>/dev/null 2>&1` part of that job is supposed to essentially disgard the content of the wget. Is that correct?

Note: the url of the wget is a script that loads up pages so that they can be pre-cached. However, this is on a seperate disk and so, shouldn't be the source of the shortage itself.

Ive since run this command:

```
du -hx / | sort -h
```

and got the following as being the biggest folders / disk hogs:

```
101M    /home/CC-Elektra/libmemcached-1.0.18/tests/libmemcached-1.0
102M    /var/lib/clamav/clamav-f466e78bcfc7d8692ae98abcd6950f0b.tmp
106M    /home/CC-Elektra/libmemcached-1.0.18/tests/.libs
110M    /var/cache/apt-xapian-index
110M    /var/cache/apt-xapian-index/index.2
123M    /lib/firmware
138M    /lib/modules/3.13.0-115-generic/kernel/drivers
138M    /lib/modules/3.13.0-116-generic/kernel/drivers
141M    /usr/lib/python2.7
168M    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
174M    /usr/share/webmin
178M    /var/lib/apt
178M    /var/lib/apt/lists
181M    /lib/modules/3.13.0-115-generic/kernel
181M    /lib/modules/3.13.0-116-generic/kernel
182M    /usr/bin
185M    /lib/modules/3.13.0-115-generic
185M    /lib/modules/3.13.0-116-generic
217M    /usr/src
219M    /home/CC-Elektra/libmemcached-1.0.18/tests
254M    /var/lib/clamav
315M    /var/cache
319M    /home/CC-Elektra/libmemcached-1.0.18
320M    /home/CC-Elektra
321M    /home
370M    /lib/modules
521M    /lib
543M    /var/lib
560M    /usr/lib
683M    /usr/share
699M    /var/log
1.6G    /var
1.7G    /usr
4.2G    /
```

Everything above that is less than 100M, although there are a bunch of folders that the command doesn't appear to have permission to access.

How can I dig down further?

Comment: I have a question - are you absolutely certain the `wget` is actually running in your external directory?  `wget` stores data to the hard drive, and if your cache and storage are both on the `/` drive then that may explain where things're blowing up on your disk.  (That is, if you want `wget` to store to the external directory you need  to add `cd /path/to/extdir/ &&` before the wget item)

Comment: No, I mean the cache that is being warmed is on another directory. Hence it's not a case of the cron building the cache and the cache filling up the disk. I also want wget to not store anything. Hence, I'm hoping to establish where the command above does keep anything from the wget. Essentially I want wget to load the url and then trash anything it collects.

Comment: The lines above that in the command output would show you which subfolders of /usr and /var are the biggest. But 4.2 G is very little. How big is your root partition?

Comment: @Tilman 28GB it's a crappy limitation of Azure.

Comment: updated my question @Tilman

Comment: Run the command under `sudo` to see all folders. (Edited my answer.) Between 28G and 4.2G there's a lot of space unaccounted there.

Comment: @Tilman That's done the job. sudo was an obvious move but when your under pressure and a relative noob, the fear of killing everything run rabid. Anyway, that command has now revealed that one exceptionally large website is taking up nearly all of drive. I know it should be on another drive / partition, but it's size was a bit of an issue in moving it over along with the other sites. It's now grown excessively large over the last week or so, that I hadn't realised just how big it actually now is. I guess I'm going to have to move it asap.

Comment: Glad you got it solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fruitless to speculate. Look for yourself where the disk space is being consumed. Run something like

```
sudo du -hx / | sort -h
```

`du` will list recursively how much space each folder occupies on your disk. The `-x` option will limit this to one filesystem, and `-h` will select "human readable" output format. It is run under `sudo` to make sure it can report on all folders regardless of their access permissions. The `sort` command sorts the output by size so the biggest folders will appear at the end. (Add the `-r` option to have them at the beginning instead.)

So this will show you the biggest folders on your root partition (assuming that's the one running out of space) at the bottom. Then look what kind of files are accumulating there.

Comment: Great. I've just run that and updated my question. Let me know what the best course of action would be. Thanks.

Comment: Would you mind breaking down what each bit is for future reference?

Comment: I guess I could check `man du`